# Meteor 1.3 NPM: Unexpected reserved word import

Tags: node.js, cordova, meteor

I'm trying to follow the guide here:

https://guide.meteor.com/using-packages.html

Installing a few node packages then trying to import them into my `methods.js` file but Im getting the following error:

```
W20160423-15:08:57.338(9)? (STDERR) app/server/methods.js:1
W20160423-15:08:57.338(9)? (STDERR) (function(Npm,Assets){(function(){import Fibers from 'fibers';
W20160423-15:08:57.338(9)? (STDERR)                                   ^^^^^^
W20160423-15:08:57.343(9)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
W20160423-15:08:57.344(9)? (STDERR)     at /repos/myproject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:278:30
W20160423-15:08:57.344(9)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160423-15:08:57.344(9)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Volumes/320gb/macbookpro/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.1rz3z4t++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160423-15:08:57.345(9)? (STDERR)     at /repos/myproject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:133:5
```

My packages seems to be installed correctly. Not sure what's causing this, Is this a bug?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error occurs if you don't add `ecmascript` packages. I think (not sure), this is added by default for newer projects but needs to be added explicitly when updating from previous versions of meteor. Try adding this package using,

```
meteor add ecmascript
```

Last time, I also faced similar problem, I came to know about it from this [link](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6146).

Comment: That worked out perfectly. I thought this was included in Meteor 1.3 by default. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, also `ecmascript` is installed correctly. Any idea what else could cause this issue ?

Comment: @AlexandreBourlier Sorry, I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already added the `ecmascript` package another issue that can trigger this kind of error output is incorrect usage of ES6+ features.

For example, redeclaring a variable within the same scope or trying to re-assign to a variable declared with `const`.

It's a horrible error output, but it basically means the transpiler can't parse the file and create an AST properly.