# How do I correctly import my collection definition?

Tags: meteor, collections, import

How do I correctly import my collection definition?
I get this error message when as a result of trying to import

[image: The displayed error message]

I externalized my collection definition FROM the main myMeteorApp.js file:
(My directory structure looked like this:)

```
/myMeteorApp
/myMeteorApp.js
```

...TO the tasks.js file: 
(My directory structure currently looks like this:)

```
/myMeteorApp
--/imports/api/tasks.js
```

The contents of tasks.js look like this:

```
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";

const Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});

const buyList = new Mongo.Collection("BuyList");
const WhoAreWe = new Mongo.Collection("whoDb");
const merchantReviews = new Mongo.Collection("MerchantReviews");
const Messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages", {transform:     function (doc) { doc.buyListObj = buyList.find({sessionIDz: {$in: [doc.buyList]}}); return doc; }});

export { Images };
export { buyList };
export { WhoAreWe };
export { merchantReviews };
export { Messages };
```

**I have packages babel-preset-es2015 and ecmascript installed, but these haven't helped.**

Looking forward to your help...

Comment: Do you have the `ecmascript` package installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor 1.3 NPM: Unexpected reserved word import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807423/meteor-1-3-npm-unexpected-reserved-word-import)

Comment: @MasterAM Hi I tried installing the ecmascript package: `meteor add ecmascript` and the response I get is:
`ecmascript without a version constraint has already been added`

Comment: @MasterAM installed the ecmascript pacakage but still getting the same error message. The link you included wasnt of help. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try this on a new project and isolate the issue. Please specify your meteor and package versions (`.meteor/packages`).

Comment: @MasterAM   `Package: meteor@1.6.0` Do you want me to send you the list of installed packages?

Comment: @MasterAM As you advised, I created a new project and externalized the task.js file in different folder and it does not give any error messages, however I now get this error message in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: buyList is not defined(…)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127833/discussion-between-masteram-and-sirbt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is the chat session we had indicates that your original app used Meteor 1.2, which did not support ES2015 modules. In addition, you did not `import` them correctly.

Here is a short checklist for `import`-related issues:

1. Make sure that your project is actually using Meteor v1.3+ (run `meteor --version`). Earlier versions did not support the modules feature.
2. Make sure that you have the `ecmascript` package installed (run `meteor list` or `cat .meteor/packages | grep ecmascript` from your project's root directory. If not, `meteor add ecmascript`. This is the package used for compiling ES2015.
3. Make sure that you are [using it correctly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export). There are 2 types of exports:

   - **default** - `import foo from 'imports/bar'` goes with `export default bar`.
   - **named** - `import { foo } from 'imports/bar'` goes with `export const foo = ...`, etc.