# "import" keyword doesn't work in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have the following line of code:

```
import { Index, MinimongoEngine } from 'meteor/easy:search'
```

It triggers the following error:

> import { Index, MinimongoEngine } from 'meteor/easy:search';
>   // 1 W20170922-20:13:44.414(4)? (STDERR) ^^^^^^
>   W20170922-20:13:44.414(4)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved
>   word

I tried `meteor add ecmascript` as it was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807423/meteor-1-3-npm-unexpected-reserved-word-import)

My questions are:
1) Do I have to update Meteor to the latest version (1.5.2)? ( I am currently using 1.2.1)

2) If the answer to the above question is NO then, how can I make it work?

NOTE: The whole project stops working when I update meteor to the latest release.

Comment: Does it also crah if you update to a newer but not the newest release, e.g 1.5? Did you also try after update to call `meteor update --all-packages` and `meteor npm update`

Comment: I think you need to install babel